# how to format grails list in g:select

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Here's a sample grails g:select to be rendered in a gsp:

```
<g:select name="user.company.id"
          from="${Company.list()}"
          value="${user?.company.id}"
          optionKey="id" />
```

And the HTML would look something like this:

```
<select id="user.company.id" name="user.company.id">
<option value="1">ABC Company</option>
<option value="2">XYZ Company</option>
</select>
```

So the company domain has entries for:

ABC Company
XYZ Company

I'm trying to format the text of each option, so the user would see:

```
Some text - ABC Company:
Some text - XYZ Company:
```

How can I format the output of Company.list() to include pre and post text for display in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `optionValue`.

```
<g:select name="user.company.id"
          from="${Company.list()}"
          value="${user?.company.id}"
          optionKey="id"
          optionValue="Some text - ${it.name}:" />
```

provided `name` depicts the `name` of the `Company` (ideally the former case works if you have `toString()` implemented in Company to return the `name` by default)

Further reading on [optionValue](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/select.html).

Comment: It worked with a modification.  As-is a gsp exception was created.  In the grails docs they use a double closure such as:

optionValue="${{'Company ' + it.description + ': '}}"  When I used the double closure the exception went away.